# Pytorch Vectorize Pairwise Gaussian/Normal Density Evaluations

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, probability, pytorch

In Pytorch, I have three tensors `A`, `mu`, and `sigma`, all with shape `B x N x M`.

I want a new tensor `D` of shape `B x N x M x B`, where every entry is the normal density of an entry of `A` with respect to a pair of parameters in `mu` and `sigma`. More concretely:

```
D[i,j,k,l] = univariate_normal_density(A[i,j,k] | mu[l,j,k], sigma[l,j,k])
```

In other words, each entry of mu and sigma is a mean and variance of a distribution. It doesn't matter whether `D` holds probabilities or log-probabilities, incidentally. Also, note that one can unfold the second and third dimensions, I think I am missing something there.

> What is the most efficient way to do this?

The most straightforward way seems to be:

- Create `B*N*M` objects of type `torch.distributions.normal`, so that 
  `N[l,j,k]=N(mu[l,j,k],sigma[l,j,k])`
- For each one, evaluate `log_prob` on `A` like `D[i,j,k,l] = N[l,j,k].log_prob(A[i,j,k])`

I can speed this up via: `D[:,j,k,l] = N[l,j,k].log_prob(A[:,j,k])`, but this still seems undervectorized. I cannot seem to find any built in methods that would do better though.

Comment: @kmario23 As in pytorch, it's the log density function of the gaussian distribution.

Comment: @kmario23 No, sorry, it's the `log_prob` method of the `torch.distributions.normal.Normal` distribution object.

Comment: @kmario23 They are variable :)  You could use something like `A = torch.randn(4,3,2)`, for example? Sorry if I misunderstand.

Comment: The [normal PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) has a pretty simple form; implementing it directly in NumPy array operations seems reasonable. The built-in functions tend to not vectorize over mu and sigma.

Comment: @WelcometoStackOverflow Yeah, I think that would not be too bad. But I prefer to use built-ins as much as possible, and I was hoping there would be one here.